Asking for resources/information about almost homogeneous linear system of equations over a finite field.
I was trying to solve a problem and it turns out that it is equivalent to asking the following question: "Does a particular set of linear homogeneous equations, $f_1,\dots,f_n\in \mathbb{Z}_2[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ say, have a non-trivial solution over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ when we stipulate that the variable $x_1$ should take the value $1$ in the solution tuple?"
I know about theorems which talk about non-trivial solutions when the system is homogenous (for e.g. Chevalley’s Theorem), but I am not unaware of the these kind of results where we have a system of linear homogenous equation, plus an equation $x=1$. Can anyone guide me towards some resources that might be useful? Thank you very much in advance!

The equations are linear, so the methods from linear algebra resolve this. If the general solution of the homogeneous system leaves $x_1$ undetermined, then such solutions exist. Otherwise they don't.

Thank you for the insight @JyrkiLahtonen :)
